# C: key press in background

Tags: c, background

So I would like to create a program which will press a key that the user chose and press that key inside and outside the program.

For example: If the user chose the key 'W' than it will be always pressed, also if I choose to switch to notepad. The program will stop after another key is pressed.

The program should be written in C language and work on Windows OS.

This is what I got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    printf("Which key do you want to be pressed?\n");
    c = getchar();
    printf("Press any key to stop the key pressing\n");
    while (1) {
        putchar(c);
        if (kbhit())
            break;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This specific program only works **in the program** but not outside the program. What should I do?

Comment: You can use [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) function , but it is specifically for windows as per your requirement.

Comment: Probably you need to read about Windows programming and particularly hooks [Keyboard hooks]

Comment: @ameyCU with this function I can get the specific key. How can I **set** a key now?